# NEVPNManager in OS X 10.11 . how can connect to a PPTP VPN connection.

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

In NEVPNManager (OS X 10.11) there are only 2 protocol classes - NEVPNProtocolIPSec and NEVPNProtocolIKEv2.

how can I connect to PPTP VPN type.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? [so] isn't a code writing service. You should put in some effort into your questions and show your code.